# Encapsulation of putpixel is terribly slow in JavaFx

Tags: java, performance, javafx

I am trying to write a simple rendering engine in JavaFx and I manage encapsulate putpixel in the way that I pass x,y coordinates and color and it draws pixel of that color to the screen. I also wrote `drawLine()` that draws line between x1,y1 and x2,y2.

Today I wrote a function `drawRectangle()` which uses `drawLine()`, but the problem is that drawing rectangles is immensely slow ( 300x300 px rectangle takes around 3 seconds to draw ). I think it is because how I am accessing the backbuffer and drawing pixels.

I am including snippets of code for putpixel, drawLine and drawRect have pretty good time complexity and they are for sure not causing bottlenecks:

```
public class Graphics
{
   private int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
   private int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;


   private Canvas          canvas; //pixel buffer
   private GraphicsContext gc;    
   private WritableImage   img; //layer
   private PixelWriter     pw;


   public Graphics()
   {
      this.canvas = new Canvas( SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT );
      this.gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
      this.img = new WritableImage( SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT ); //layer
      this.pw  = img.getPixelWriter();
   }

   public void createWindow( Stage primaryStage )
   {
      Stage window = primaryStage;

      window.setOnCloseRequest( new EventHandler< WindowEvent>()
      {
      public void handle( WindowEvent e )
         {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit( 0 );
            Platform.setImplicitExit( true );
         }
      });

      window.setTitle( "Fasa3D" );

      GridPane grid = new GridPane();
      grid.getChildren().addAll( this.canvas ); //put pixel buffer into layout


      Scene scene = new Scene( grid,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT );
      window.setScene( scene );
      window.show(); //present pixel buffer
   }


   public void putPixel( int x,int y,Color c )
   {
      this.pw.setColor( x,y,c );     //accessing pixel by coord;
      this.gc.drawImage( img,0,0 ); //draw layer onto pixel buffer
   }
}
```

I would be infinitely thankful if you could please help me out with optimization. The whole repo is [here](https://github.com/TheTask/Fasa3D).

Comment: Well, why are you redrawing a whole 600x600 image after placing a single pixel? That gc.drawImage() doesn't belong in putPixel()

Comment: @user158037 yeah I was really confused what are different purposes of Canvas, WritableImage, PixelWriter and GraphicsContent and I was just glad I managed to encapsulate it. I moved the gc.drawImage() to a separate function, call it once per frame instead of once per putpixel and the performance is at least 10000 times better.